# Can I add a table into the message body with Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I am working with Outlook Add-in. I have a task pane in message compose form which includes some textareas. Is it possible to add these information to the message body as a table?

The following is the part of my task pane ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to set and get body content of the message while in compose. Generate HTML table filled with user input you would like to appear in the message body. Retrieve current message body content with [`getAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.Body?view=office-js#getasync-coerciontype--options--callback-) function. Add/insert the table you have generated into message body and set it back by using [`setAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.Body?view=office-js#getasync-coerciontype--options--callback-) function. You may also use [`prependAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.Body?view=office-js#prependasync-data--options--callback-) function to manipulate with message body. Please read more information at [Get and set item data in a compose form in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-and-set-item-data-in-a-compose-form).

Comment: Dear sir, I am going to try and share results. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir. It works fine. I share the example code below as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is just showing how to work(For 3 inputs). As you see in the question I have a button. Now I am able to add input's value which is in the taskpane to the message body as table by clicking button.

```
 $("#btn1").click(function () {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
      "html",
      { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
      function callback(result) {

        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
          '<table style = "background-color: red">' +
          '<tr>' +
          '<th>Shipment</th>' +
          '<th>Payment</th>' +
          '<th>Validity</th>' +
          '</tr>' +
          '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + $("#shipmentText").val() + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + $("#paymentText").val() + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + $("#validityText").val() + '</td>' +
          '</tr>' +
          '</table>',
          { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }

        )
      })
  });
```